# how to fetch records whose date_of_leaving is nil or it should be in particular range of dates in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date-range

I want to write a `query` on `employee` model, where the `employee` `date_of_leaving` is `nil` or it should be in the particular `date range`.

Here is my current query:

```
e = Employee.where.not('date_of_leaving >= ? and date_of_leaving <= ?', Date.today - 60, Date.today).where(:date_of_leaving => nil)
```

but its returning `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: where chaining is `AND`. See answer from @Andrey Deineko for correct query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will return all employees which have `date_of_leaving` either between specified dates or is `nil`:

```
Employee.where('date_of_leaving BETWEEN ? AND ? OR date_of_leaving IS NULL', Date.today - 60, Date.today)
```